# Find all projects building a SCM repository

Tags: jenkins

We have a lot of jobs on our Jenkins instance and people often struggle to find the jobs they are interested in (email notifications, dashboards etc. notwithstanding).

I've put together a Groovy script that finds all jobs that checkout a given repository address: https://gist.github.com/jakub-bochenski/e152affa4719b0794a3311fcc7abe590

Is there a better solution? I can't find any search plugins etc.

If there is no ready-made solution for this, then maybe the script can be implemented in a cleaner way:

- currently it handles `AbstractProject`, `WorkflowJob` and `WorkflowMultiBranchProject` separately as I couldn't find any common logic
- it only handles `SubversionSCM` and `GitSCM` as I don't know of any abstract way to get a "remote URL"

Answer (score 1):

Try job grouping and organizing with dashboard views, we have more than 7000+ jobs and this comes handy with more than 200+ users accessing.

Comment: We do that too, with standard views and https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Monitor+Plugin but people still find the search useful even if only to find "stray" or legacy jobs that are not included on the dashboards